# Is it possible to change the color of a substring in a string or set it as different html tag if it is a prop set as string?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Having a React component that accepts as a prop a string:

```
interface MyProps {
  myInput: string;
}

export function MyComponent({ myInput }: MyProps) {
   ...
   return (
     <div>
       {myInput}
     </div>
   );
};
```

And this component is used somewhere else:

```
  <MyComponent myInput="please contact us at test@test.com" />
```

My question is, can we change the color of the email address in this case? For example to be blue.

Or even better, to wrap that text into:

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com" target="_blank">
   test@test.com
</a>
```

Not sure if it's possible to do something like this if the prop is of type `string`.

Comment: how about using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` here, having anchor tag as the same you had but as a string ?

Comment: Email is a sensitive data, are you sure you want to rely on a string that does not have to include it? Imo it should be a separate field/prop with applied validation.

Comment: Consider creating a prop that accepts JSX or allowing your component to work with the `children` prop. That way the person using the component can style the text as they wish.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it based on the string you provide but it'd be much easier to provide the email address as a separate property to `MyComponent`.

Without changing the component I'd use some simple RegExp to get the email from the string and then you'd be able to do anything you want with it.

A quick example with an **incomplete and simplified** RegExp:

```
const SUPER_SIMPLE_EMAIL_REGEX = /[a-z0-9.]{1,}@test.com/gi; // Don't use this one

export function MyComponent({ myInput }: MyProps) {
   const match = myInput.match(SUPER_SIMPLE_EMAIL_REGEX);

  if (!match.length) {
    return (
      <div>
        {myInput}
      </div>
    );
  }

  const textWithoutEmail = myInput.replace(match[0], '');

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{textWithoutEmail}</span>
      <a href={`mailto:${match[0]}`} target="_blank">
        match[0]
      </a>
    </div>
  );

};
```

This is a very simplified solution but I think you can use this in your case.